# A way to reset all messages in a Spring Integration context

Tags: java, spring-integration

We have a Spring Integration context with 2 Aggregators, some transformers, adapters, etc... 
This context is consuming messages from ActiveMQ queues, and also 2 webservices, and put them into an Aggregator.
What we want to achieve is that every time we receive a message in a concrete queue, we reset all messages in the Aggregators, and in every statefull component to start every batch process ( triggered by an start message in a queue ) totally blank and clean.

So, how to reset the Aggregator components based on a message received in a queue ?

Comment: I wonder why correlation strategy doesn't work for you to achieve a batch boundaries, starting with that specific message...

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand you. The problem is that in the middle of a  batch process , we can receive another message of batch started, so we should discard and kill the current information and start again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use-case isn't clear for me, but what you want to get can be achieve using `MessageGroupStoreReaper`:

```
 * Convenient configurable component to allow explicit timed expiry of {@link MessageGroup} instances in a
 * {@link MessageGroupStore}. This component provides a no-args {@link #run()} method that is useful for remote or timed
 * execution and a {@link #destroy()} method that can optionally be called on shutdown.
```

If you configure it for the aggregator's `MessageGroupStore`, it will perform the callback registered from there:

```
store.registerMessageGroupExpiryCallback(
            (messageGroupStore, group) -> this.forceReleaseProcessor.processMessageGroup(group));
```

And if you don't configure anything else on the aggregator, your messages will be discarded (by default to `NullChannel`) and group will be removed from the store.

So, when that type of message is arrived, you should call the `MessageGroupStoreReaper.run()` and only after that send it into the process.